# error al compilar : NULL used in arithmetic

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio y tengo un error al compilar.

Me piden una función recursiva que evalue boolean si un binario es avl .

Mi duda es :
¿Compilando con g++ no tendría que el circuito corto evitar el error NULL used in arithmetic ? 
Copio el código y agradezco ayuda.

```cpp
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct nodoABB 
{
    int dato;
    int h;//altura 
    nodoABB* izq; 
    nodoABB* der;
};
typedef nodoABB* ABB;

//recursiva chequear balanceo
bool balanceado (ABB t)
{
    bool bal=true; //valor de null
    if (t!=NULL)
    {
        bal=balanceado(t->izq) && balanceado(t->der) && (t->izq->h ==NULL || t->der->h==NULL || (abs(t->izq->h - t->der->h)<2) );
    }
    return bal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, lo que tienes es **un aviso** (*warning*), no un error.

Dicho aviso se produce aquí: `t->izq->h ==NULL` y aquí: `t->der->h==NULL`; según tu `struct nodoABB`, `h` es un `int`. Y eso es todo: **no debes comparar un `int` con un puntero**.

Supongo que lo que querías hacer es

```
... && (t->izq->h==0 || t->der->h==0 || ...
```

> ... no tendría que el circuito corto evitar el error ...

No. Te estás confundiendo. El aviso se produce **en tiempo de compilación**, que no tiene nada que ver. El compilador sabe que, de entrar en esa parte de la comparación, la operación a realizar es potencialmente problemática.

Es **en tiempo de ejecución** cuando se realizan las operaciones y se entra o no en esa parte del código. Pero entonces ya sería tarde. C++ no realiza comprobaciones en tiempo de ejecución, y es imposible que te avise de nada llegado ese momento.

En cualquier caso, tu código `t->izq->h ==NULL` **se ejecutará siempre**. No hay cortocircuito que valga. Tus operaciones son:

```
EXP1 && EXP2 && ( EXP3 || EXP4 || EXP5 ...
```

En esa secuencia, tanto `EXP1` como `EXP2` y `EXP3` se ejecutaran **si o si**. Solo el resto de las expresiones se verían afectadas ( `EXP4` y `EXP5` **no se ejecutan** si `EXP3` evalúa como `true`).